# How to subtract two rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to PowerBI, and confused as to why DAX is subtracting one count column to the sum count of another column. Attached it is a screenshot of what I mean. I would rather it simply subtract 1 row count to another 1 row count. For example Count of hb_number - count of bw_id (12476 - 12006) NOT (12476 - 600674)

[image]

Comment: What's the formula for Measure?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 tables that are not related to each other.

Comment: @JoaoLeal, here is the formula:
Measure =  COUNTA('Conversion'[hb_number]) - COUNTA('LifeConv2'[common_id])

Comment: @mxix, yeah I found this out later. The issue is that I'd need to join the two tables with multiple joins. Benefit_ID, Plan_ID, and Option_ID. I'm not sure how to do that in Power BI

Comment: Create a new column with those values concatenated with a separator on both tables and join by that one

Comment: @mxix, awesome thanks! I had to also add a relationship between the two tables using the merged columns

Comment: @Everett can you provide litle more details? it is a litle confusing. As mxix said the lack of a relation may cause measures to not iterate row wise. But there are more factores that play a role in dax when it comes to context evaluation. Try 
calculate( COUNTAX(, 'Conversion''Conversion'[hb_number]) - COUNTAX(,'LifeConv2'['LifeConv2'[common_id]), userelationship (<provide columns that would connect both table>) Not sure it works because i don't have enough info. CONTAX iterates measures row wise as opposed to COUNTA

Comment: @pedromagalhaes, no worries. I was able to figure it out with mxix's comment. I just needed to create a relationship between the two.